# How to access request object inside middleware on Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to get the Request object inside a middleware. I'm creating an ajaxOnly middleware,  and need to check the isXhr() request method. I tried to create something like follow:

```
 $ajaxOnly = function($request, $response, $route) { // this is the line 3
             if (!$request->isXhr()) {
                Slim::redirect('/dashboard/');
             }
            };
```

And using like that:

```
$app->get('/posts/:start_date/:end_date', $ajaxOnly, function($start_date, $end_date) use($app) {
    echo 'ok';
});
```

But it's giving me the following error:

Slim Application Error The application could not run because of the
following error:

- Code: 2 Message:
- Missing argument 1 for {closure}()
- File: /var/www/myapp/routes.php Line: 3

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that, slim doesn't pass any parameters to the Closure, so you get that error, try something like this

```
$ajax = function(){
    $slim = Slim::getInstance();
    if (!$slim->request()->isXhr()) {
            $slim->redirect('/dashboard/');
    }
};
```

Comment: Since slim 2 you'll need to use `$slim = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();`

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this.

```
$ajaxOnly = function($app) {
    if (!$app->request()->isXhr()) {
        $app->redirect('/dashboard');
    }
};
```